# Shell script to read file line by line and compare to variables

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a file with name `emp.txt`, which contains columns `empname` and `empid`. Now I want to read the file, both `empname` and `empid`, and compare to variable `empname` & `empid` entered by users at the time of login. If both matches it, should login, otherwise display message `>login invALID`.

Below is my file `emp.txt`.

```
empname    empid**
aruna       sm223
santhosha   sm224
chandan     sm456
```

I have written a function, whatever is mentioned above not getting. below is my function.

```
function user () { 
  echo
  echo -e "Enter Your Name : \c"
  read usrname
  echo
  echo -e "Enter Your Employee-id : \c"
  read empid
  if [ "$usrname" = "" ] || [ "$empid" = "" ]; then 
    echo 
    echo " Please enter your name & empid."
    user
  fi
}
```

Comment: Do you mean "if the `empname` and `empid` entered by the user can be found in the file, both on the same line, then login"?

Comment: yes sir..what ever user entered empname & empid it should match with empname & id in the file, If matched it should login other wise it should not.

Comment: Sir, OS Oracle Linux 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `function` *and* `()`; just `()` is more portable.

Instead of `echo "Enter your name"; read`, you can use

```
read -p "Enter your name: " usrname
```

Now, at the end of your function, you have both `usrname` and `empid`. To loop through your file and check if they match existing entries, you can use

```
read -p "Name: " usrname
read -p "ID: " empid
while read -r user_entry empid_entry; do
    if [[ $user_entry = $usrname && $empid_entry = $empid ]]; then
        echo "Logging in"
        exit    # Or return from function
    fi
done < emp.txt
echo "Login invalid"
```

This is skipping your validity check, it's just to show how to loop through the file. Once both name and ID match, we have to branch elsewhere; if we reach the end of the loop, the attempt is considered failed.

To make sure that `empname` and `empid**`, the column names, aren't accepted as usernames, you could replace `< emp.txt` by `< <(tail -n +2 emp.txt)`, which skips the first line.

<sub>This works with Bash 4.3.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, benjamin sir, But why its not reading any values inside while loop

Comment: read -p "Name: " usrname
read -p "ID: " empid
while read -r user_entry empid_entry; do
    if [[ $user_entry = $usrname && $empid_entry = $empid ]];
    then
       echo "valid"
       read -p "oracleusername: " orauser
       exit
    fi
done < emp.txt
echo "Login invalid"
~

Comment: @ChandanHp It does read a new line every time you hit the `while read`.